# Dynamic parser compilation into JVM bytecode

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I need to implement a dynamic parser generator able to run in Seco (tiny IDE works Mathematica-like cell-based notebook).

Is ANTLR, or any other parser generator, able to compile grammar from String (contents of preselected cell) dynamically into JVM bytecode? I mean instantly compiling grammar description into executable parser object.

Preferably without using any workarounds like temp files and calling `System("java -jar antrl grammar.g")`

Taking in mind porting to Android without dynamic bytecode: what parser generators supports it's own bytecode interpreter targetted on parsing?

Comment: Why generate bytecode instead of just generating normal Java objects?

Comment: Antlr is a parser generator, not a compiler. It creates java classes that parse the File/String into an abstract/attributed syntax tree that can be used to create bytecode. No idea what a dynamic parser is; a parser that reacts to changing grammars? Antlr based parsers are static, you need to recreate the classes everytime you change the grammar. It will be some work to write your own bytecode generator with custom language. You might want to describe your use case in more detail; i'm certain there is an easier approach.

Comment: debugging byte code can be a pain, I suggest generating Java code which you compile first and once it is working skip that step.

Comment: dynamic parser -- executable java object able to parse and process scripts and text data in java Strings, created itself _in runtime_, no any files from grammar definition till resulting AST in HyperGraphDB

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://github.com/julianthome/inmemantlr ? (Not tested, just stumbled over it...)

Comment: [parboiled] https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki can be used to create dynamic grammars. Still no automatic creation of bytecode from the ast.